Import object dynamically from index file
I have 3 classes in three different folders and based at country value at run time, the appropriate class object is created.
src/canada/index.ts
export const country = new Canada();


src/england/index.ts
export const country = new England();


src/spain/index.ts
export const country = new Spain();

There are some common code which needs to access the country object created. I tried to dynamically pass the path like import {country} from 'src/${country}/index.ts' but looks like dynamic import is not available in ES ["target": "ES2021", "module": "CommonJS"].
I have also tried const countryObj = await import('src/${country}/index.ts') , but I get this error
 Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'preserve', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
Is there a way I can have access to the country specific object from a different file?

You cannot do this with import thing from "dynamic ${} path", but you should be able to use const thing = await import( "dynamic ${} path" ) for that.

Ive tried that But it says - Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', 'nodenext', or 'preserve', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

If you are using import statements then your code should already be set to module? CommonJS uses the require syntax, which should also support dynamic strings as all it takes is a string as the argument? You can also do this without top-level await, or you could wrap your entire code in an async function and call that directly, as it is supported inside async functions.

If you want to do dynamic import use the following syntax, within an async function or a callback approach.
 const {country: _country} = await import(`src/${country}/index.ts`);
 // or
 import(`src/${country}/index.ts`).then(({country: _country}) => { 
    console.log(country);
 });



Dynamic Import: Use dynamic import to import the appropriate class object based on the country value. Dynamic import allows you to import modules conditionally at runtime.

Construct the Import Path: Construct the import path dynamically based on the country value:
async function getCountryObject(country) {
  let countryObject;
  try {
    // Construct the import path based on the country value
    const modulePath = `./${country}/index.js`;

    // Dynamically import the module based on the constructed path
    const module = await import(modulePath);

    // Access the country object from the imported module
    countryObject = module.country;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors related to dynamic import
    console.error('Error importing country module:', error);
  }

  return countryObject;
}

// Usage
const country = 'canada'; // Replace with the actual country value at runtime
getCountryObject(country)
  .then(countryObject => {
    // Use the country object as needed
    console.log(countryObject);
  });



Hope this helps!
